# How can the a surrogate code point (0xD800-0xDFFF) in C++ cause program errors?

Tags: c++, unicode, emoji, surrogate-pairs

The following is a description of the cppreference:

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

> Range of universal character names
>
> ...
>
> If a universal character name corresponds surrogate code point (the range 0xD800-0xDFFF, inclusive), the program is ill-formed.

I had a crash due to emoji characters, but I can't repeat it. I want to know is it because of the range 0xD800-0xDFFF problem?

Why is there a compile error at `a:`, but no runtime error at `b:`?

My example:

```cpp
// ""  \uD83D\uDC76
// a:
// std::cout << "\uD83D\uDC76" << std::endl; // compile error

unsigned char e1 = 0xD8;
unsigned char e2 = 0x3D;
unsigned char e3 = 0xDC;
unsigned char e4 = 0x76;

unsigned char e[] = {e1, e2, e3, e4, '\0'};
// b:
std::cout << "e:" << e << std::endl; // Print �=�v, but there are no runtime error.
```

Comment: Are you refering to "If a universal character name does not correspond to a code point in ISO/IEC 10646 (the range 0x0-0x10FFFF, inclusive) or corresponds to a surrogate code point (the range 0xD800-0xDFFF, inclusive), the program is ill-formed. " ? Please quote literally or make it more clear what you modified

Comment: The reference is rather obtuse. A _single_ surrogate code point is an error because it's an incomplete sequence. What exactly your program does also depends on the output encoding. You seem to be hard-coding UTF-16BE which is arguably a bad idea. (If your target is Windows, UTF-16LE would probably be marginally better.) The reference seems to be talking about the `\u1234` notation anyway, not your individual bytes; in this notation, a surrogate pair is also not permitted.

Comment: Ill-formed = compilation error. If your code crashes, that's not it.

Comment: The proper Unicode escape for your character is `\U0001f476`

Comment: your code isn't printing any unicode characters, its printing 4 separate ascii characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different behaviour, because the code is semantically different.

First: the interval of code-points you cited are named "surrogates", and they are used to encode codepoints above the old 16-bit limit with the old UCS-2 encoding (so 2 bytes per character): using two surrogates (and in correct order) one can describe all Unicode codepoints. But so, it will not be possible to describe surrogate codepoints (they will be interpreted as part of a two code units).

Now, for your case: the first case you get exact such problem: you are using an invalid codepoint, and also possibly the encoding of sources is UTF-8, so the compiler may be confused: do you mean it need to merge the two codepoints and inject UTF-8 of all sequence, or just a invalid (but possible) two UTF-8 codepoints? (the later is named CESU-8 encoding)

The second part is different: you create an array of bytes, the compiler will not try to interpret it as text: just as a sequence of bytes. In fact you can put binary data. So it is valid. Just the output is explicitly encoded as UCS-2 (or also UTF-16 if the surrogates are put in the correct order), so the terminal must interpret the data correctly. Note: you also forced a precise type of UTF-16 or UCS-2 (the endianess may be different, so on different architectures you may get different result and so not surrogates).

Note: some operating system and languages quickly went to UCS-2, so you may get some documentation which uses *surrogates* explicitly (see e.g. JavaScript, where you may have some function which work at UCS-2 (or "Unicode code units") and other at UTF-16 ("Unicode code points"), so you may find emojii described as code units (2 bytes units) and not code points (2 or 4 bytes if the code units are surrogates).

Also note: in parallel to UTF-8, there is also CESU-8, which practically it is a UTF-8 encoding, but at UCS-2 level, so encoding each surrogate parts separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the `the program is ill-formed` described in `cppreference` does not cause runtime errors?

Comment: @lidajun your program isn't ill formed, it doesn't contain any universal character names so the rule doesn't apply

Comment: You use the escape sequences/names only on the first part. In the second, it is just binary data. C++ has no ideas you want to interpret it as text. (cout may be a hint, but you can redirect it.. and there is no rules you cannot feed terminals with invalid sequences. -- in fact: it could be just a program which write in Latin1 or in CP1252 (windows encoding for western languages): the bytes/string is valid.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have a crash that solves it after filtering the emoji symbol. If this is not the reason, I don't know what the reason is. Thank you.

Comment: @lidajun: it you use emoji, use `\U0001f476`. Forget the code unit encoding used by JavaScript people (and so many websites). It is an historical problem of JavaScript (compatibility: code was run on many old browsers, so no way to change interpretation: programmers have no control of the full stack).

Comment: The string received by my program contains the emoji symbol, so I want to use the second to simulate. But I didn't get the conclusion I wanted.

Comment: So: how do you handle the string? It seems you get an UTF-16 string, but then you want to use as UCS-2, and you expect that printing it as UCS-2 will be correctly interpreted (but probably the terminal expect a UTF-8). So I recommend you to annotate your code with the expected encoding on each step, so see where you have missed a decoding-encoding part.

Comment: I use C++11 std::string to receive and process string. Everything is normal when there is no emoji. When there is emoji, Occasionally crash. If my experiment is incorrect, can I know how to test it?

Comment: @lidajun if you add a [mre] to your question of the code that's actually causing the problem and the error message that you see then we might be able to help

Comment: std::string is a bit generic (and C++ will not trans code when you read the data), so you should really understand the encoding of the original string. And also where the program crash may be relevant. But I think that should be ev. asked in a new question (with real code).